# What is appropriate design pattern

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have some problem on deciding which design pattern to use in my situation. My  problem is as follows: I have to build a testing platform to perform some tests on physical devices the company I work for produces. So I have:

1) ITest interface, which is parent for all interfaces:

```
interface ITest
{
   string Description {get; set;}
   void Run();
}
```

So particular test should inherit from this interface and implement Description property and Run method.

2) TestManager class, which holds the collection of tests to run. It also may perform some actions on tests, say for example it has RunAll method which runs all tests it holds.

```
class TestManager
{
   public List<ITest> Tests {get; run;}
   void RunAll()
   {
       foreach (var t in Tests)
       {
           t.Run();  
       }
   }
}
```

Now suppose that some tests need some preparations before running. So I have subtype of ITest which have a preparation text for test:

```
interface IPreparableTest : ITest
{
   string PreparationMessage {get; set; }
}
```

This PreparationMessage  is gonna be prompted to user in some way so that the user can perform some actions on device we wanna test. But it is the TestManager's responsibility to decide what tests need to be prepared and in what way the PreparationMessage is gonna be shown to user. The problem is that it holds the collection of ITest and therefore it have to distinguish between preparable test and ordinary test. Of course i could've written something like this:

```
RunAll()
{
   foreach (var test in tests)
   {
       if (test is IPreparableTest)
       {
          MessageBox.Show(((IPreparableTest)test).PreparationMessage);
       }
       test.Run();
   }
}
```

But I don't want to write like this because it is not OOP style. I wanna use some pattern here, but I don't have any idea which one I should use. Also I don't want to put the preparation logic on test, because it's not the responsibility of test, test should have only the information on how to prepare the device, but how this message is gonna be shown to user is up to TestManager. So basically I want to learn the way to avoid the switch on type of object.

Comment: Why not just have `ITest` have a `BeforeRun` and `AfterRun` method? Classes that don't need to implement it can just have blank methods. You seem to be highly coupled to the UI, that isn't quite right.

Comment: Or even just move the prep message into `ITest` and check if it is empty? Either way, this question is too opinion based for Stack Overflow I'm afraid.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel.  Unless this is just an exercise, use NUnit or XUnit.  They are well supported in CI/CD, and can output results to various test reporting tools.  They are supported directly in VS.

Comment: I see no apparent advantage in the interface inheritance. Favor multiple interface implementation over interfaces inheriting from each other.

Comment: *want to* only takes one more character to type than *wanna*.

Answer (score 2):

You should take guidance from existing test libraries (like NUnit, or XUnit).  They have methods that can run before and after a set of tests, and before and after each test.  They also use reflection to work out if a method should be executed.

Pseudo code:

```
[TestClass]
class MyTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public void ThisIsATest()
    {
    }

    [BeforeAllTests]
    public void OncePerClass()
    {
    }

    [BeforeEachTest]
    public void OncePerTest()
    {
    }

    [AfterEachTest]
    public void AfterEachTest()
    {
    }

    [AfterAllTests]
    public void AfterAllTests()
    {
    }
 }
```